# Check endings of an String without built-in methods like endsWith() in Java

Tags: java, string, char

I want to check if every word in an string has specific endings with various length. I can't use arrays & methods for this like endsWith(). The only methods im allowed to use are charAt() and length().

```
public class TextAnalyse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(countEndings("This is a test", "t"));
        System.out.println(countEndings("Waren sollen rollen", "en"));
        System.out.println(countEndings("The ending is longer then every single word", "abcdefghijklmn"));
        System.out.println(countEndings("Today is a good day", "xyz"));
        System.out.println(countEndings("Thist is a test", "t"));
        System.out.println(countEndings("This is a test!", "t"));
        System.out.println(countEndings("Is this a test?", "t"));
    }

    public static int countEndings(String text, String ending) {
        int counter = 0;
        int counting;
        int lastStringChar;

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            lastStringChar = 0;
            if (!(text.charAt(i) >= 'A' && text.charAt(i) <= 'Z' || text.charAt(i) >= 'a' && text.charAt(i) <= 'z') || i == text.length() - 1) {
                if( i == text.length() - 1 ){
                    lastStringChar = 1;
                }
                counting = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j + lastStringChar < ending.length() && i > ending.length(); j++) {
                    if (text.charAt(i - ending.length() + j + lastStringChar) == ending.charAt(j)) {
                        counting = 1;
                    } else {
                        counting = 0;
                    }
                }
                counter += counting;
            }
        }

        return counter;
    }
}
```

The actual results are that I get one counting less, I guess its because it dont check the last chars properly.

Comment: Start at the last character, work your way back through the two strings checking if the corresponding characters match.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `substring` and `equals`? :-D

Comment: Or, better, `regionMatches`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It should check how many words in that string ends with the letter "t", in this case it should be one. Sadly im not allow to use that methods :D

Comment: @DavidDo2015 - Okay, that makes sense. I'd split the string into an array of words, then loop the array. In any case, your best bet when trying to figure out why your code isn't working is to step through the code statement-by-statement using the debugger built into your IDE.

Comment: How is it supposed to work if you only preserve a single char, yet try to look for words that end with `"en"`?

Comment: "one counting less" is not correct (as I see): second test is returning `3` - I would say that is expected; thrid is returning `1` - actually one more than expected (Hint: add an empty space to the end of text and remove the `lastStringChar` - will make everything a bit easier)

Comment: Thank you Carlos! Thats solved 90% of my problems with my existing code, now my only problem is that it count incorrectly if I have 2 special chars behind each other like "Test? Test" I mean the question mark and the space. How could I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution I can come up with is the following:

Check, if a word ends with a given suffix:

```java
public static boolean endsWith(String word, String suffix) {
  if(suffix.length() > word.length()) {
    return false;
  }
  int textIndex = (word.length() - 1);
  int suffixIndex = (suffix.length() - 1);
  while(suffixIndex >= 0) {
    char textChar = word.charAt(textIndex);
    char suffixChar = suffix.charAt(suffixIndex);
    if(textChar != suffixChar) {
      return false;
    }
    textIndex--;
    suffixIndex--;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Split the given in its' words and use the above method to count every word ending with the given ending:

```java
public static int countEndings(String text, String ending) {
  {
    //maybe remove punctuation here...
    //(if yes, use String.replace for example)
  }
  String[] words = text.split(" ");
  int counter = 0;
  for(String word: words) {
    if(endsWith(word, ending)) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Also consider to remove unwanted punctuation, like '!' or '?' (...) - the above implementation will not recognize count any word ending with `t` in the `String` `test!`!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are able to use regular expression.

If you want count words with ending, you can use the following code:

```
public static int countEndings(String text, String ending) {
    final Matcher wordWithEndMatches = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Za-z]*" + ending + "\\b").matcher(text);
    int count = 0;
    while(wordWithEndMatches.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```